# Is "for all I know" without may/might/etc. "correct"?

Tags: phrases

I have seen "for all I know" used in both of the following forms:

- For all I know, he may as well be Santa in disguise.
- For all I know, he's Santa in disguise.

From what I've understood so far, both forms mean the same thing, more or less (they're both wild speculation).

Are both forms considered equally acceptable in scholarly spheres etc., or is one considered "to avoid"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct definition and usage of "for all I know"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92207/what-is-the-correct-definition-and-usage-of-for-all-i-know) (... I saw some sentences using this phrase "for all I know" but wasn't quite sure what is its exact definition _and also whether a modal verb such as "could, may or might" expressing uncertainty must be present in the sentence_.)

Comment: I'm not sure that scholarly spheres welcome wild speculation regardless of how one expresses it.

Comment: In this example pair, as both are obviously at least fairly exasperated remarks, and the content is meant to be taken as ludicrous (probably classifiable as a _hyperbolic_ paraphrase of "I haven't any idea who he is"), I'd say the modal verb on top of the modal comment clause is a redundancy achieving nothing positive here and eroding the punchiness of the second variant. At the duplicate, licensing of the non-use of a modal verb (or modal adverb such as 'probably') alongside 'for all I know' is evidenced.

Comment: As @EdwinAshworth points out above, there is a redundancy. In terms of grammar, this double encoding is due to some commonalities between the category of epistemic modality ("may": the speaker does not present the depicted state of affairs as certain) and evidentiality ("For all I know: the speaker declares that the depicted state of affair stems from some source of information and shouldn't accordingly be taken for certain).

Comment: So "for all I know" in and of itself, implies modality, and the form with modal verbs, if anything, is the "bad" one?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't find an answer to my question in any of the other question's answers! And I had, in fact, seen that other question (and its answers) before posting.

Comment: 'Less good', not 'bad'. And 'For all I know, he may be Santa in disguise' would seem the obvious variant to the punchy variant, and this sounds almost as good as that. The 'may as well' string sounds out of place here. "I might/may as well go home now" means that I can see no advantage in staying and  "I might/may as well give up" connotes (at the very least) resignation. The situation is different with "He migh just as well be Santa in disguise," where 'just as well' conveys merely 'equally probably' (though one would hope the speaker was being tongue-in cheek – or 3 years old).